# how can I add more then one reply annotations using itextpdf-5.4.4.jar

Tags: java, pdf, itext

in sandbox.annotations.AddInReplyTo, there is a sample of create only one reply annotations, i want to add more then two reply annotations, refering to the sample, i want to use the following code to ceate two reply annotations. but, the pdf created can be open in adobe acrobat pro or adobe reader, but the content of reply annotaion is both "Hello PDF 01", the "Hello PDF 02" of replySticky2 can not be displayed, is something wrong in my code? thanks for your help!!!

```
    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    PdfDictionary sticky = annots.getAsDict(0);
    PdfArray stickyRect = sticky.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
    PdfDictionary popup = annots.getAsDict(1);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
    Rectangle stickyRectangle = new Rectangle(
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(0).floatValue(), stickyRect.getAsNumber(1).floatValue(),
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue(), stickyRect.getAsNumber(3).floatValue()
    );
    PdfAnnotation replySticky = PdfAnnotation.createText(
            writer, stickyRectangle, "Reply-01", "Hello PDF 01", true, "Comment");
    replySticky.put(PdfName.IRT, annots.getAsIndirectObject(0));
    stamper.addAnnotation(replySticky, 1);        

    PdfAnnotation replySticky2 = PdfAnnotation.createText(
            writer, stickyRectangle, "Reply-02", "Hello PDF 02", true, "Comment");
    replySticky2.put(PdfName.IRT, annots.getAsIndirectObject(0));
    stamper.addAnnotation(replySticky2, 1);

    stamper.close();
}
```